# When is a re-meld legal in two-handed pinochle?

Tags: pinochle

Before the stock has been exhausted, the player who just won a trick in two-handed Pinochle may make a meld, which falls into following categories (reproduced below for convenience).

What are the exact circumstances under which you can reuse already melded cards in a new meld and how many points is the new meld worth?

The rule that I've commonly heard is that reusing a card in a meld in a different category than *the category of the meld it is currently part of* is always permitted. Using a card in a higher-scoring meld of the same category only adds the difference between the old meld and the new one, e.g. Royal Marriage (+40) --> Trump Sequence (+110) . This gives a score of (+150) overall exactly as if the trump sequence had been melded on a single turn.

There's some ambiguity here. If I do the following actions on three consecutive turns.

1. Meld a Royal Marriage (+40)
2. Meld Four Queens using the queen from the Royal Marriage (+60)
3. Meld a Trump Sequence (?)

On turn three should I score +150 or +110? The king in the sequence was previously used in a royal marriage, but the queen was not.

4 of a kind (one per suit)

```
4 Aces   -- 100
4 Kings  --  80
4 Queens --  60
4 Jacks  --  40
```

Marriages and Sequences

```
Trump Sequence  -- 150
Royal Marriage  --  40
Common Marriage --  20
```

Pinochle

```
Single Pinochle --  40
Double Pinochle -- 300
```

Dix

```
Dix -- 10
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you are asking.  First you meld a royal marraige (K+Q) and then later meld a complete run (A+T+K+J).  Now there is a run with an extra king on the table.  I was taught to play it that the run was 150 and included the first marriage but each additional king or queen was 40 more points. So I would subtract 40 that I took before and then add 190 for this meld.  It turns out that I am not the only one that scores this way - here is someone else that uses the same rules and scoring I learned: pagat.com/marriage/pinmain.html I have no idea what the "official" rules say.

Comment: Like I said in a previous comment, I have no idea who is authorized to claim that they have the authoritative rules, but https://www.pagat.com/marriage/pin2hand.html has some info under "Special notes concerning melding" which are the same as what I commented before,   Bicycle make decks of cards so if you are using Bicycle cards then maybe https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/pinochle-2/ is authoritative enough - it has examples under "Melding"